# Pump data into ActiveMQ from a JDBC data source

Tags: jdbc, activemq-classic

We have an application provided by a third party which takes a stream of market data (provided by said third party), and writes it into a JDBC compatible database.

The only configuration parameters it has are the JDBC connection string, plus settings allowing us to pick what pieces of data we'd like to be stored in this database.

This is very good for static data, but we'd like to feed this data into our internal ActiveMQ messaging fabric (in addition to writing it into the DB).

The database updates are triggered by pushes of market data to us. I'd like to have this application write the data directly to a set of MQ topics by implementing some kind of jdbc "facade" that would re-route the data directly into MQ.

What I don't want to do is poll the database for new information - as I want to keep the same fluidity of the data (e.g. fast moving stocks will generate a lot more data than slow moving - and we'd want to retain this).

Advice and pointers are very much welcome!

Answer (score 0):

[Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) is the answer, but potentially only if you're ok with polling the database. It's great for integration issues like this. If there was some other trigger that you could work with, you could use that to cause the database to be read.

Comment: Unfortunately what I really don't want to do is poll - I want to achieve a true "push" from the data source, so the flow of the stream is maintained.

Would it be possible to initiate the poll with a trigger? That could be a workaround for this, but I didn't think it was possible to activate external processes with a trigger (DB is MySQL)